# How to pull date/time in french format for wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, timestamp, posts

I am working on a wordpress post in which **I want the date/time in frech format as shown below:**

```
ENGLISH

By FJ
Published April 9, 2019 at 4:05 p.m.
Last updated April 9, 2019 at 4:14 p.m.


FRENCH

Un texte de FJ
Publié le 9 avril 2019 à 16 h 05
Mis à jour le 9 avril 2019 à 16 h 14
```

I have used the following code to pull the date/time in english/french for wordpress post:

```
<strong><?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en') { ?>
        By
    <?php } else { ?>
        Un texte de
    <?php } ?><?php the_author(); ?> </strong><br>
<strong><?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en') { ?>
        Published <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        Publié le <?php the_time('j F, Y'); ?>
    <?php } ?> <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en') { ?>
        at  <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        à   <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>
    <?php } ?>  </strong><br>
<strong><?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en') { ?>
        Last updated <?php the_modified_time('F j, Y');
    } else { ?>
        Mis à jour le <?php the_modified_time('j F, Y');
    } ?><?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en') { ?>
        at <?php the_modified_time('g:i a');
    } else { ?>
        à  <?php the_modified_time('g:i a');
    } ?>  </strong>
```

The above code **displays the following o/p**. English is fine but french doesn't seem to work.

```
By FJ
Published April 9, 2019 at 4:05 p.m.
Last updated April 9, 2019 at 4:14 p.m.

Un texte de FJ
Publié le avril 9, 2019 à 4:05
Mis à jour le avril 9, 2019 à 5:14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try declaring different date formats on the "ifs" for the french format, looks like this

```
<strong><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){ ?>
By
<?php }else{ ?>
Un texte de
<?php  } ?><?php the_author(); ?> </strong><br>
<strong><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){ ?>
Published <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
<?php }else{ ?>
Publié le <?php the_time('j F, Y'); ?>
<?php  }  ?> <?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){ ?>
at
<?php }else{ ?>
à
<?php  }  ?> <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?> </strong><br>
<strong><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){ ?>
Last updated <?php the_modified_time('F j, Y'); ?>
<?php }else{ ?>
Mis à jour le <?php the_modified_time('j F, Y'); ?>
<?php  } ?><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){ ?>
at
<?php }else{ ?>
à
<?php  }  ?> <?php the_modified_time('g:i a'); ?> </strong>
```

Comment: @JonGozalez It didn't work. Its giving me the same o/p.

Comment: @flash I just tried it without doing the ifs and it shows me the date in both formats